# Can a PTAS be called one if it is parameterized by one of the problem inputs (in addition to ε)?

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, approximation, parameterized-complexity

I.e. is it right to say "a PTAS parameterized by *sth*"?

Is it unusual, and is it correct?

Comment: PTAS is probably not what you would call such algorithms, no. They seem to be called *Parameterized Approximation Schemes* (PAS). Wikipedia-link here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parameterized_approximation_algorithm

Comment: @Highheath Thanks, you're right.